# Get ID of a row having maximum value in other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like

```
+------+-------+-------------------------------------+
| id   | col2  | col3                                |
+------+-------+-------------------------------------+
| 1    | 1     | 10                                  |
| 2    | 1     | 20                                  |
| 3    | 1     | 15                                  |
| 4    | 2     | 10                                  |
| 5    | 2     | 20                                  |
| 6    | 2     | 15                                  |
| 7    | 2     | 30                                  |
+------+-------+-------------------------------------+
```

I want to select Id where col3 has maximum value and col2 = 2. (id 7 in this case since it has maximum value 30 where col2=2). I tried with GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT id, MAX(col3) FROM table_name 
WHERE col2 =2 
GROUP BY id
```

But it gives me all the Id's where col2=2. How can I achieve desired output?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use this following simple sql query for your requirement.

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID
FROM table_name 
Where col2 = 2
ORDER BY col3 DESC
```

You can use also `ROW_NUMBER()` function. It's another way for same result.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
CREATE TABLE temp(
    ID      INT,
    Col2    INT,
    Col3    INT
)
INSERT INTO temp VALUES 
(1, 1, 10), (2, 1, 20), (3, 1, 15),
(4, 2, 10), (5, 2, 20), (6, 2, 15), 
(7, 2, 30);

SELECT
    ID, Col3
FROM(
    SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col3 DESC) 
    FROM table_name
)t
WHERE
    rn = 1
    AND col2 = 2
```

**RESULT**

```
ID          Col3
----------- -----------
7           30
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple sub-query will do the job:

```
SELECT id 
FROM table_name 
WHERE col2 = 2 
AND col3 = (SELECT MAX(col3) FROM table_name WHERE col2=2)
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c77b5/3/0)

This can return multiple ID's if there are multiple rows with the same max-value, if you don't want that you could use `DISTINCT id` or an aggregate function like `MAX(id)` or `TOP 1 id`.

Here's another approach using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 MAX(id)
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY col2, col3
HAVING col2 = 2
ORDER BY col3 DESC
```